# Taking the address of operator<< fails in gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write a trait to detect if a arbitrary type has an insertion operator defined for it. To do that I wish to use std::is_same<> to compare the type of the function pointer to the expected type. I have a problem exhibited by the following code

```
#include <iostream>
class A {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  return os;
}
int main()
{
  decltype(static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(ostream&, const A&)>(&operator<< )) foo = nullptr;
  std::cout << foo << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

in gcc 4.8 with --std=c++11

```
test2.cpp:12:81: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  decltype(static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, const A&)>(&::operator<< )) foo = nullptr;
                                                                                 ^
```

The error does not appear in clang or more recent versions of gcc however for production we must be able to compile in gcc 4.8. Is there a workaround for this in GCC 4.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that version of GCC doesn't parse this correctly. To work around this, you can declare an alias to the function pointer type:

```
using op_type = std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, const A&);
decltype(static_cast<op_type>(&operator<< )) foo = nullptr;
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60b835ada368657b)

Comment: Thought that the issue might have been the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/23061912/560648, but it's not, so I don't know why I'm writing this comment

Comment: I had assumed the problem was with operator<< rather than the pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ostream&`, write `std::ostream&`:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
{
  return os;
}
int main()
{
  decltype(static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, const A&)>(&operator<< )) foo = nullptr;
  std::cout << foo << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like [that ICEs GCC 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37c539ab386e56de).