# Syntax error in constructor taking default argument `std::map`

Tags: c++, clang

Consider simple code snippet

```
#include <map>
#include <string>


struct Foo
{
    Foo(const std::map<std::string, int> & bar = std::map<std::string, int>())
        :bar(bar)
    { }

    std::map<std::string, int> bar;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it like this: `clang++ -o foo foo.cpp` I face errors:

```
foo.cpp:7:73: error: expected ')'
    Foo(const std::map<std::string, int> bar = std::map<std::string, int>())
                                                                        ^
foo.cpp:7:8: note: to match this '('
    Foo(const std::map<std::string, int> bar = std::map<std::string, int>())
       ^
foo.cpp:7:68: error: expected '>'
    Foo(const std::map<std::string, int> bar = std::map<std::string, int>())
                                                                   ^
```

Same behaviour for **clang 3.2** and **clang 3.3**.

So I am wondering if I missing something or is it a bug? GCC does not complain.

Comment: Can you try `{}` instead of `()`?

Comment: Yes it seems to be a bug in your versions of clang. Tested with clang version 3.5.0 (trunk 203891) and it works fine.

Comment: It compiles in glang++ 3.5 (pre-3.5 from last week or so) and gcc 4.8.2, as well as clang 2.9 and g++ 4.6.3. Which is all the compilers I have on my current machine...

Comment: @stefan same errors. It looks like parser error so I doubt that changing `()` to `{}` had any chance to fix it :)

Comment: If you can't upgrade clang to a later version, then you can work around it by making a default constructor (i.e. one without any arguments).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yeah, I know, there are ways to workaround. For example typedef. But I wanted to be sure it's a bug...

Comment: I don't know why your compiler is complaining about that code. However a tip:
If you pass a const container, you should do it by reference, because you won't modify it, and copying a container can be expensive. :P

Comment: @Melkon, good point! It's just a typo (snippet is obviously not a original piece of code :D). Thank you for pointing out! I'll edit to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fallacy in the C++ grammar that will surprise you. I'm unsure if this has been rectified or cleared out, see below.

All major compilers accept it though, including newer versions of Clang.

A list of references pertaining to the issue:

- [Clang did not fix this because Standard says so](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13421)
- [Clang fixed this for compatibility](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13657)
- [The working group issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325)
- [a dupe question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851584/default-template-class-argument-confuses-g)

Comment: So, being a standard-paranoid type, I am wondering. Is is piece of code is considered t be vaild. If it's not, will it be fixed in next C++ standard so that it become valid?

Comment: @GreenScape: I can't tell from the working group issue comments. The safe path is to use a typedef, IMHO. In any case, that won't be bad practice, even if you just do `using map_string_int = std::map<std::string, int>;`. It's still mind-boggling to me that the grammar forbids this.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yeah, from the "user's" perspective this seems unnatural. Thank you for help!